# Callback for stopUpdateLocation

Tags: objective-c, callback, gps

Have a quick question: wanted to set the default value for location if the `gps` searches for location for too long.

And implemented the folowing solution:

```
CLController = [[CoreLocationController alloc] init];
CLController.delegate = self;
CLController.locMgr.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers;
[CLController.locMgr startUpdatingLocation];
[self performSelector:@selector(stopUpdatingLocation:) withObject:@"TimedOut" afterDelay:30];
```

However don't know if
1) The `stopUpdateLocation` is going to happened :)
2) How to callback a function for `afterDelay` is there a way to specify multiple function to call? Or is there a way to override `stopUpdateLocation`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

i didn't understand your question, didn't you implement the stopUpdatingLocation method?

Anyways, u can do something like that:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(stopUpdatingLocation:) withObject:@"TimedOut" afterDelay:30];

 - (void) stopUpdatingLocation:(NSString*)_timeout
{
    NSLog(@"passed in stopUpdatingLocation with string: %@", _timeout);

   [CLController stopUpdatingLocation]; <-- you need to use THIS code for stop updating!!
}
```

So you are sure that method is call. For override the method just need to implement it ^^